# Type int in python: how to check type

Tags: python, types, typeerror, raiserror

I use the code:

def foo(x):
    print(type(x))
    if x is not int:
        raise(TypeError)
    #do smth

foo(100)

The log is , but TypeError is raised. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use if type(x) is not int:

```
def foo(x):
    print(type(x))
    if type(x) is not int:
        raise(TypeError)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if im reading it right it should be:

`def foo(x):
    if type(x) is not int:
        raise(TypeError)
  foo(100)`

Im really not sure what you mean with log but maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `isinstance()` rather than `type() ==`. The former works for subclasses.